# Not able to add cordova plugins

Tags: cordova, npm, cordova-plugins

I am trying to add cordova plugin to my project. I was successfully doing it till yesterday. But suddenly I am not able to add plugins from my local system. It gives me the following error.

> $ cordova plugin add C:\Users\ankur\CoolPlugin
>       Fetching plugin "C:UsersankurCoolPlugin" via npm
>       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/C%3AUsersankurCoolPlugin
>       npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/C%3AUsersankurCoolPlugin
>       Fetching from npm failed: 404 Not Found: C%3AUsersankurCoolPlugin
>       Error: 404 Not Found: C%3AUsersankurCoolPlugin
>       at RegClient. (c:\Users\ankur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
>       rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client
>       \lib\request.js:268:14)
>        at Request.self.callback (c:\Users\ankur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
>       rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:140
>       8:22)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at Request. (c:\Users\ankur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cord
>       ova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:876:
>       14)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
>       at IncomingMessage. (c:\Users\ankur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
>       les\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index
>       .js:827:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
>       at _stream_readable.js:908:16
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

I am not able to figure out why is it throwing an error that " Error: 404 Not Found: **C%3AUsersankurCoolPlugin**" when I am running cordova plugin add **C:\Users\ankur\CoolPlugin** . And surprisingly I am able to add a plugin from github successfully.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the local path of the folder which contains your plugin.xml file.

In case it still fails, you can maybe try uploading your plugin to git and pulling it from there.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. I just found out that I had to put the local path in quotes.